# R: gsub and str_split_fixed in data.tables

Tags: r, data.table, gsub, strsplit

I am "converting" from data.frame to data.table

I now have a data.table:

```
library(data.table)


DT = data.table(ID = c("ab_cd.de","ab_ci.de","fb_cd.de","xy_cd.de"))
DT

         ID
1: ab_cd.de
2: ab_ci.de
3: fb_cd.de
4: xy_cd.de  

new_DT<- data.table(matrix(ncol = 2))
colnames(new_DT)<- c("test1", "test2")
```

I would like to to first: delete ".de" after every entry and in the next step separate every entry by the underscore and save the output in two new columns. The final output should look like this:

```
   test1 test2
1    ab    cd
2    ab    ci
3    fb    cd
4    xy    cd
```

In data.frame I did:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c("ab_cd.de","ab_ci.de","fb_cd.de","xy_cd.de"))
df

         ID
1: ab_cd.de
2: ab_ci.de
3: fb_cd.de
4: xy_cd.de


df[,1] <- gsub(".de", "", df[,1], fixed=FALSE)
df

      ID
1: ab_cd
2: ab_ci
3: fb_cd
4: xy_cd



 n <- 1
for (i in (1:length(df[,1]))){
    new_df[n,] <-str_split_fixed(df[i,1], "_", 2)
    n <- n+1
}
new_df

  test1 test2
1    ab    cd
2    ab    ci
3    fb    cd
4    xy    cd
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tstrsplit` to split the column into two after removing the suffix (*.de*) with `sub`:

```
DT[, c("test1", "test2") := tstrsplit(sub("\\.de", "", ID), "_")][, ID := NULL][]

#   test1 test2
#1:    ab    cd
#2:    ab    ci
#3:    fb    cd
#4:    xy    cd
```

Comment: what do I need the [] for at the end?

Comment: `[]` here is a trick to print the result out. As `:=` modify columns in place but doesn't return anything. If you don't need to print, then you don't it.

Comment: I need to repeat every row 5 times. i tried `... :=rep(tstrsplit(sub.....),16)` but this is  adding columns, not rows

Comment: You can repeat rows afterwards. like so `DT[, c("test1", "test2") := tstrsplit(sub("\\.de", "", ID), "_")][, ID := NULL][, lapply(.SD, rep, each=5)]`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   extract(ID, into = c('test1', 'test2'), '([^_]+)_([^.]+).*')
#  test1 test2
#1    ab    cd
#2    ab    ci
#3    fb    cd
#4    xy    cd
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT[, .(test1 = sub('_.*', '', ID), test2 = sub('[^_]+_([^.]+)\\..*', '\\1', ID))]
#   test1 test2
#1:    ab    cd
#2:    ab    ci
#3:    fb    cd
#4:    xy    cd
```