# data.table syntax setting colnames and values based on values in other table via tstrsplit

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

after solving [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217340/r-gsub-and-str-split-fixed-in-data-tables) and being still new to data.table I need help with a similar problem but cannot get it to work:

I want to create a new dt that has the colnames of `DT_1` split by [+-] as colnames

```
DT_1= data.table("t+e+s+t" = c(8),"t+e+s-t" = c(8))
        t+e+s+t t+e+s-t
1:      8        8
```

and gets colnames of `DT_2` as row entries

```
DT_2 = data.table("+++-" = c("a","b"), "++-+" =c("e","f")) 

      +++- ++-+
1:    a    e
2:    b    f
3:    c    g
4:    d    h
```

so the final table looks like

```
   t   e   s   t
1: +   +   +   -
2: +   +   -   +
```

Since I need the entries of table DT_1 & DT_2 later on I want a new data.table. I tried:

```
DT_final = data.table(str_split_fixed(colnames(DT_1), "[+-]")= c(tstrsplit(colnames(DT_2), "")))
```

It might not be possible to solve this in one line.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
result <- as.data.table(tstrsplit(names(DT_2), ""))
names(result) <- unlist(strsplit(names(DT_1)[1], "[+-]"))

> result
   t e s t
1: + + + -
2: + + - +
```